# JSON table encountered too many errors

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have to upload a JSON load into the big query. While uploading the load I got the below-mentioned error.

I debug and found that it is failing on this JSON record which seems to be valid.

```
{"firebaseUid":"00FKNF7x2BQhDoPk9TSzE4Ncepn1","age_range":{"min":21},"signUpApp":"stationApp","uid":"00FKNF7x2BQhDoPk9TSzE4Ncepn1","locale":"en_US","emailSha256":"501a8456ececb2a50e733eed6c64b840d63d3aad99fb9ad4a1bbd2cbc33fc1f6","loginMethod":"facebook","notificationToken":"dummy","ageRangeMin":21,"pushNotificationEnabled":true,"projectId":"triplembaas","createDate":"13/07/2018","state":"QLD","station":"TripleM 104.5","facebookId":"1021TheHotBreakfast740157586","email":"connollyharley@gmail.com","cellularNetwork":"OPTUS","suburb":"Bellara","idfa":"60A63734A27E40249331658F1AC670A1","deviceId":"BBD901JaseJuelz454E100000000000000000","firstSignUpDate":"13/07/2018","name":"Harley Connolly","gender":"male","emailVerificationFlag":false,"lastUpdateDate":"20/07/2018","link":"dummy"}
```

Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.

Comment: How do you upload it? Maybe you need to include the header `Content-Type: application/json` in your upload-request.

Comment: I'm uploading the file from my local. I have uploaded JSON data multiple times from my local to bigquery and it has succeeded without giving any headers. I don't think bigquery expects a header.

Comment: It needs to be newline-delimited JSON. In your question, it doesn't appear to be valid NDJSON.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Can you please point out where does it disqualify as ndjson? I uploaded a similar looking record and it worked.

Comment: The row's contents are spread across multiple lines, not just one...

Comment: That's just in the StackOverflow format. Data is actually in a single line which is why I have posted this query. Corrected in the question.

Comment: There is any clear error there neither in the error message. Could you post that *similar looking record* to compare them?

Comment: How do you define your schema (autodetect or manually) and what does the error stream shows?

Comment: I'm specifying the schema as autodetect. Error stream shows:"message": "Invalid date: '17/08/2018' Field: createDate; Value: 13/07/2018". I'm confused because the similar data got loaded a day before. Is this happening due to schema autodetect?

Comment: Could you provide us some row of that similar data which worked the day before?

Comment: After analysis, I found that createDate key stores the value in dd/mm/yyyy format. For Example: "createDate":"01/02/2016". With the autodetect feature on, bigquery considers this field as Date format. How does bigquery detecting the data type is what I would like to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is some info about [how date-type format works](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date-type). Could you post a row which worked with the one that doesn't just to compare since a priori anything is wrong in the non-accepted row?

Answer (score 4):

Probably I am late but for anyone still looking for answer try this.
Change your date format to "YYYY-MM-DD". Somehow bigquery detects that the field value is Date and it won't allow any other format of date instead of "YYYY-MM-DD"